# How to use False Positives metric in Tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, keras-metrics

In Tensorflow 2.0, I'm trying to build a model that classifies my objects onto two categories: positives and negatives.

I want to use `tf.keras.metrics.FalsePositives` and `tf.keras.metrics.FalseNegatives` metrics to see how the model improves with every epoch. Both of these metrics have assertions stipulating: `[predictions must be >= 0]` and `[predictions must be <= 1]`.

The problem is that an untrained model can generate an arbitrary number as a prediction. But even a trained model can sometimes produce an output slightly above 1 or slightly below 0.

Is there any way to disable these assertions?

Alternatively, is there any suitable activation function that forces the model outputs into `[0, 1]` range without causing any problems with the learning rate?

Comment: The ```sigmoid``` activation function is a suitable alternative if outputs must be in the range ```[0, 1]```.

Comment: In my case, technical specification says that I must use `tanh`, so I'm limited to using `tanh` only.

Comment: @stephen_mugisha, but that's a good idea in general. I can add the `sigmoid` layer just for the purpose of validation and then remove it in production. Could you please add it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: sure..sometimes you may also choose to use other activation functions in your hidden layers but use sigmoid for the output layer so that the range of outputs is between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sigmoid` activation function is a suitable alternative if outputs must be in the range [0, 1] as it also ranges from `0 t0 1`.